# О казаках и казахах

Tags: этимология

Может, это глупый вопрос, но случайно ли такое созвучие у слов "казак" и "казах"? И почему иногда, особенно в украинком языке, пишут "к**о**зак", а иногда - "к**а**зак"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем точная формулировка. По-русски - казак, по-украински - козак. Украинский вариант отражает более древнюю фонетику и исторически более "правилен". И не украинское О результат отсутствия аканья, а наоборот - русское А развилось вследствие его, аканья, наличия. В отношении украинских казаков и в историческом аспекте по-русски также возможно написание "козак".

Answer (score 0):

По сведениям Фасмера, в русский язык слово КАЗАК заимств. из тур., крым.-тат., казах., кирг., тат., чагат. kаzаk "свободный, независимый человек, искатель приключений, бродяга". Сюда же казАки мн., соврем. казахи -- тюрк. народ.  Укр. *козак*, др.-русск. *козакъ* "работник, батрак", впервые упоминаются в грам. 1395 г. Буква О в словах - результат оканья, свойственного древнерусскому и в некоторой степени украинскому языку (отсутствие редукции О в слабой позиции).

Comment: Вы правы насчет аканья. Исторически в древнерусском языке сначала было кОзак. Затем аканье, свойственное русскому языку, превратило О в А. И слово вернулось к исходному варианту kazak (сингармонизм, свойственный тюркским языкам (слова типа: карандаш, сарафан и под.), нашел отклик в русском аканье).